# Are there major advantages to choosing personal injury lawyer from the car accident city?

Tags: united-states, jurisdiction, lawyer, litigation, negligence

If a car accident occurs in city X is there major reason to choose a personal injury lawyer from X? Or is it sufficient to be from the same state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any attorney admitted to practice of law in the state where the accident occurred is sufficient.

In some kinds of cases, it is desirable to have an attorney who is closer to the county where the case will be filed to reduce legal fees incurred for travel time. But, since personal injury lawsuits are customarily handled by attorneys (at least in the U.S.) on a contingent fee basis, controlling legal fees for travel is not an issue.

Out of pocket costs of mileage that are payable by the client in a contingent fee case are typically trivial compared to the stakes in the case, especially now that minor status conferences are often done virtually.

Comment: "controlling legal fees for travel is not an issue" wouldn't the fees still come out of any money the plaintiff receives if they win?

Comment: @Someone In a contingent fee arrangement for a personal injury lawsuit, the lawyer gets a percentage of the recovery without regard to the number of billable hours spent pursuing the lawsuit.

Comment: @ohwilleke  In a percentage contingent fee arrangement are there still charges and fees that are paid by the person who hires the lawyer?

Comment: @Maesumi Usually, out of pocket costs are paid by the person who hires the lawyer (although often, not until the end of the case, with costs advanced in the meantime). The biggest of these are expert witness fees. Other costs usually paid by the client include filing fees, photocopies, jury notebook stationary costs, trial exhibit production charges (e.g. oversized blow ups of pictures or documents), postage, certified copy charges, mileage charges of witnesses and attorneys, service of process fees, online legal research service expenses, recording fees, and court reporter charges.

Comment: @ohwilleke  Is it an acceptable practice (and wise for the person who hires the lawyer) to put all these costs as a preset percentage of the recovery?

Comment: @Maesumi "Is it an acceptable practice" Not really.

Comment: @Maesumi Rules of Professional Conduct 1.5 and 1.8 generally prohibit this (although advanced costs may be forgiven if there is no recovery). See https://www.cobar.org/rulesofprofessionalconduct The Colorado Rules of Professional Conduct are linked but all U.S. jurisdiction organizes their rules of professional ethics in the same way with some substantive differences in the details of these rules.

Comment: @ohwilleke: Would a local lawyer have better awareness of the local landscape? E.g., I've seen some lawyers discuss cases where they wore a suit and the judge thought it to be pretentious.  However, I've normally seen that in the context of being permitted to practice outside their home state, so I'm unsure if this sort of thing is relevant when traveling the shorter distance their their home town.

Comment: @Brian There are some kinds of cases where it could matter, but in a car accident case, it is unlikely to make much of a difference. Few cases involve grounds to thrown out the case before trial, the key decisions are made by juries, and the evidentiary issues to be resolved by the judge during trial are typically pretty mundane. It also has no real partisan valence. Perhaps 90-95% of the time, the case will settle before trial anyway.